# oracle sql inline query identifier not valid

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following  oracle sql query

```
select tren,origen,area
from (
select cod_serv tren,a.origen origen
from r_incidencias r,
(select tren,origen
from r_trenes80_e
union
select tren,origen
from k_trenes80) a 
,
(select id_area_productiva area,cod_estacion estacion
from mer_est_area_prod meap
where a.tren = r.cod_serv
and meap.cod_estacion = a.origen
 ) f)
```

When I executed this sentence, I get the error

a.origen identifier not valid.

I want the field origen in the  table mer_est_area_prod is equal field origen in query a.

In the table mer_est_area_prod exists the field origen

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use joined table column directly in the subquery join, you can move it to where condition outside the subquery

Ex:

```
SELECT tren,origen,area
FROM 
(
    SELECT cod_serv tren ,a.origen origen
    FROM r_incidencias r,
    (
        SELECT tren,origen
        FROM r_trenes80_e
        UNION
        SELECT tren,origen
        FROM k_trenes80
    ) a,
    (
        SELECT id_area_productiva area,cod_estacion estacion
        FROM mer_est_area_prod meap
    ) f
    WHERE a.tren = r.cod_serv
    AND f.estacion = a.origen
)
```

It is better to use new ANSI sql join condition because it is clear on what you are trying to join on

Ex:

```
SELECT cod_serv tren ,a.origen origen, meap.id_area_productiva area
FROM r_incidencias r
INNER JOIN 
(
        SELECT tren,origen
        FROM r_trenes80_e
        UNION
        SELECT tren,origen
        FROM k_trenes80
) a ON a.tren = r.cod_serv
INNER JOIN mer_est_area_prod meap ON meap.cod_estacion = a.origen
```

Answer (score 1):

An inline view cannot refer to another one at the same level like this.

If you have Oracle 12c or later, you could use a [lateral inline view](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1) something like this:

```
select tren, origen, area
from   ( select cod_serv tren, a.origen origen, area
         from   r_incidencias r
              , ( select tren, origen
                  from   r_trenes80_e
                  union
                  select tren, origen
                  from   k_trenes80 ) a
              , lateral
                ( select id_area_productiva area, cod_estacion estacion
                  from   mer_est_area_prod meap
                  where  a.tren = r.cod_serv
                  and    meap.cod_estacion = a.origen ) f
       )
```

(the equivalent for ANSI joins is `cross apply`.)

Alternatively, move the join conditions outside the inline views:

```
select tren, origen, area
from   ( select cod_serv tren, a.origen origen, area
         from   r_incidencias r
                join ( select tren, origen
                       from   r_trenes80_e
                       union
                       select tren, origen
                       from   k_trenes80 ) a
                     on a.tren = r.cod_serv
                join ( select id_area_productiva area, cod_estacion estacion
                       from   mer_est_area_prod meap ) f
                     on f.estacion = a.origen
       )
```